# How can I include download attribute to link in HTML

Tags: html, download

I would like to know how to include a `download` attribute into a link. By that I mean I have this:

```
<a href="files/apple.pdf download>Download here</a>
```

However I would like to include all this into a link and then into QR code and I want to start downloading the file (or ask for download) automatically without clicking anything when someone goes to the site using the link.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to include option to force download a file from URL in QR code.

If you have access to server configuration, you should be able to overwrite file's header so the browser starts downloading it automatically.

For example, in Apache you could put this into your .htaccess file:

```
<Files ~ "\.*$">
ForceType application/octet-stream
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files>
```

This will force download of every file in a directory.
If you only want to force download specific files you could change the `*` to some other regular expression like so:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:doc|odf|pdf|rtf|txt)$">
```

or:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
```

Depending on your back end, configuration may differ.
Try searching for how to set Content-Disposition and Type headers on your platform.